# updating view based on jquery calendar's date change

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a jquery calendar on my asp.net MVC view and I want to change the data on a portion of the view based on date selected from calendar. How can I handle jquery calendar's date change event and update the portion on view ?

Regards,
Asif Hameed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [onSelect](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onSelect) event handler when setting up your binding and then either call an action to get the updated data you want. Something along these lines:

```
$('.selector').datepicker({
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
       $('#divIdToLoadNewData').load('url/to/action');
   }
});
```